# Java 2D World: Convert from mouse screen co-ords to screen co-ordinates?

Tags: java, 2d

I have a 2D world background made up of a Grid of graphics, which I display on screen with a viewport (800x600) and it all works.

My question is I have the following code to

convert the mouse co-ordinates to world co-ordinates

then

World co-ordinates to grid co-ordinates

then

grid co-ordinates to screen co-ordinates.

```
//Add camerax to mouse screen co-ords to convert to world co-ords.    
int cursorx_world=(int)camerax+(int)GameInput.mousex;
int cursorx_grid=(int)cursorx_world/blocksize;  // World Co-ords / gridsize give grid co-ords
int cursorx_screen=-(int)camerax+(cursorx_grid*blocksize);
```

So is there anyway I can convert straight from mouse screen co-ords to screen co-ordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Something I use fairly often is a `viewbounds` variable, which is a list of three game coordinates. The first is the upper-left corner of the screen, the second is the center, and the third is the bottom right. I also use `zoom` (which looks like your `blocksize`).

When you register a mouse event, you can find its game coordinate by offsetting from the first viewbound by the coordinates of the mouse multiplied** by the zoom level.

```
// Create a new Coordinate using a copy constructor
game_coor = new Coordinate(viewbounds[0]).add(mouse_coor.multiply(zoom));
```

---

** Depending on your implementation zoom could be px/unit or unit/px, multiply or divide accordingly.